# Woocommerce - Find out an item in a shopping cart is over 50 kilos

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm using Woocommerce and I have a number of items in my shopping cart.

How do I find out if one of the items in a shopping cart is over a certain number of kgs?

For example.

> If shopping cart has an item that weighs over 50 kgs, then do XYZ.

At the moment, I can get the total weight of all the cart items using the following code:

```
$cartweight = $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_weight;
```

How do I find out if an item in a shopping cart weighs over 50kgs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. Here's my code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', 'display_custom_item_data', 10, 2 );
function display_custom_item_data( $cart_item_data, $cart_item ) {
    
    session_start();
    
    if ( $cart_item['data']->get_weight() > 0 ){
        $cart_item_data[] = array(
            'name' => __( 'Weight', 'woocommerce' ),
            'value' =>  ( $cart_item['data']->get_weight() )  . ' ' . get_option('woocommerce_weight_unit')
        );
    }
    
    $cart_item_weight = $cart_item['data']->get_weight();
    
    if ($cart_item_weight >= "30" && $cart_item_weight <= "59")
    {
        $_SESSION["weightflag"] = "delivery_options1";
    }
    elseif ($cart_item_weight >= "60")
    {
        $_SESSION["weightflag"] = "delivery_options2";
    }
    
    return $cart_item_data;
}
```